# Div positioning - Aligning one big div next to stack of divs

Tags: html, position, alignment

I'm trying to align one big div next to a stack of three smaller divs. How do i allow the big div to take place on their right?

Thanks in advance.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/zyddtxnn/)

```css
.left_stack {
    width: 350px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
}

#left_banner1 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#left_banner2 {
    background-color: red;
}

#left_banner3 {
    background-color: blue;
}

#right_banner {
    height: 225px;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: purple;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner_section">
           <div class="left_stack" id="left_banner1"></div> 
           <div class="left_stack" id="left_banner2"></div> 
           <div class="left_stack" id="left_banner3"></div>
           <div id="right_banner"></div> 
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/zyddtxnn/1/

```
#banner_section {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Parent div's width = Child's width.

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Personally, and to do this without changing the HTML, I would use the multi-column layout. This requires lots of prefixes (as shown [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn)) in order to work. Additionally to this, I removed the unique id's to the left hand column as I thought that the css selectors were more appropriate.

```css
#banner_section {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;

  -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
  -moz-column-gap: 0px;
  column-gap: 0px;
  
  width:700px;
}
.left_stack {
  height: 75px;
  width:350px;
}
.left_stack:nth-child(1) {background-color: yellow;}
.left_stack:nth-child(2) {background-color: red;}
.left_stack:nth-child(3) {background-color: blue;}
#right_banner {
  height: 225px;
  width:350px;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner_section">
  <div class="left_stack"></div>
  <div class="left_stack"></div>
  <div class="left_stack"></div>
  <div id="right_banner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about the column property, i'll give it a try.